How to make Image downloadable in AMP pages
I'm facing issue while createing a image download button in AMP page, is anyone know how we can do so?
I'm Trying to create image download link but i'm unavail to do so, if anyone know how can we  do so please help me.
#AMPIMAGEDownload
